# Parboiled2: reference to position in source text from AST

Tags: scala, parboiled2

I am writing a DSL, and learning parboiled2, at the same time. Once my AST is built, I would like to run some semantic checks and, if there are any errors, output error messages that reference the offending positions in the source text.

I am writing things like the following, which, so far, do work:

```
case class CtxElem[A](start:Int, end:Int, elem:A)

def Identifier = rule {
  push(cursor) ~
  capture(Alpha ~ zeroOrMore(AlphaNum)) ~
  push(cursor) ~
  WhiteSpace
  ~> ((start, identifier, finish) => CtxElem(start, finish, identifier))
}
```

Is there a better or simpler way?

Comment: Looks fine to me. I would consider avoiding "finish". You can probably replace it with a direct call to cursor at that position, without going through the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Parboiled 2 (for now) [doesn't support parser recovery strategies](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2#recovering-from-parse-errors). It means that if parser will fail - it will stop. As far as I remember it should print the symbol where it failed, or at least you could get the [cursor](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/blob/release-2.1/parboiled-core/src/main/scala/org/parboiled2/Parser.scala#L52)

So if you're trying to build your own DSL and you need that kind of functionality, I would propose you to use a different tool like ANTLR. Parboiled1 supports parser recovery techniques, but for now it's dead in buried if favor of support for the second version. Parboiled 2 is good in parsing of log files or configuration files (that should correct by default), but it's not good for building DSLs.

Comment: I needed this for detecting semantic errors in syntactically correct input, and it worked. Syntax error recovery was my next hurdle, so I did try ANTLR (the JS version) but the null pointer exceptions I got were disappointing. I ended up hand-coding a recursive descent parser, with error-recovery, and am very happy with the outcome.